# Trying to Deploy the React Multi-page Sample

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Looking at the REACT-MULTIPAGE sample, I have set up an MS Teams site to test this and created the custom poll list. I have run through the next set of steps as far as this part in the readme

> from the **./temp** directory create a copy of the **workbench.html**
>   file and rename it to **workbench.aspx** 
>      - in the **workbench.aspx** file change the value of the **webAbsoluteUrl** property to the absolute URL of your SharePoint site
>      - upload the **workbench.aspx** file to a document library in your site

1) Why is this needed, given post GA we already have access a workbench.aspx on our tenants e.g.
`Https//domain.sharepoint.com/sites/mymsteamsite/_layouts/workbench.aspx` ?

2) If you look at workbench.html, it doesn't have **webAbsoluteUrl** property and so the renamed file won't have one either!

3) Adding a workbench.aspx to a document library seems non intuitive. Would it be better to upload this to the SitePages or Pages library once we can circumvent the   "Access Denied" restriction.

Hope this makes sense.  Note, I can happily run the Poll web part in Localhost but would need to mockout the List and List Name as this is needed by the Poll WP.

*Sharing not Complaining*

Answer (score 0):

The sample itself is pretty old and has just recently been updated to GA, unfortunately without updating the setup steps. Originally, when the sample was published, there was no hosted workbench, so you had to copy the local file to SharePoint. As you noticed, with the hosted workbench this isn't required anymore.
The code is already updated to retrieve the URL of the context web, so you don't need to worry about the `webAbsoluteUrl` property.

Comment: Thanks @waldek,  yes that makes sense.  I notice, outside of localhost the Poll wp doesn't render correctly so I will try and figure out why this and report back.

Comment: @waledek  I have put react part though the VSCode -> chrome debugger and there seems to be an error in the hosted workbench . 
Exception has occurred: Error
Error: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=%20Check%20the%20render%20method%20of%20%60Config%60. for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.